# OpenLayers zoom to point with padding

Tags: javascript, openlayers

In my web app I have a search side bar which can return results as either a bounding box, or an X and Y coordinate with a zoom level. The sidebar pops out the side of the screen and partially overlays the map, so I want the results centred on this slightly offset map. I can do this no problem when a bounding box is supplied to the search results, as I can simply use the `padding` FitOption like so

```
//leftPadding is a pixel value equal to the width of the sidebar
//result.bbox is an Openlayers Extent
olMap.getView().fit(result.bbox, { padding: [100, 100, 100, leftPadding] });
```

However, I cannot (to my knowledge) use `.fit()` with a coordinate and a zoom level.

This is how I zoom to a point at the moment (uses animation but doesn't have to)

```
olMap.getView().animate({
        duration: 1000,
        center: convertedCoord,
        zoom:result.zoom
    })
```

`result.zoom` is an integer indicating zoom level to zoom to

`convertedCoord` is an [Openlayers Coordinate](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_coordinate.html#%7ECoordinate)

I could use `setView()` like this

```
let view = new View({
    center: convertedCoord,
    padding: [100, 100, 100, leftPadding],
    zoom: result.zoom
});
olMap.setView(view);
```

However, this shifts the actual view of the map, so rotating now rotates around that point, and when I close the sidebar I would need to reset the padding every time.

What I ideally want is some way is to `setCenter()` with padding, but I can't seem to find a way to do that. Ideally I would want the animation to still work, but if it can't so be it.

I feel there is a possibility of using [coordinate.add()](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_coordinate.html#.add) to move the center point, but I can't quite figure out how to determine the delta required to move it to get the same padding.

Comment: Resolution is your answer, since it's map units per pixel. If you need offset of 100 pixels, just add `map.getView().getResolution() * 100` to your coordinates.

Comment: The bbox of a single coordinate is `coordinate.concat(coordinate)` or you could fit using a geometry `new Point(coordinate)`.  Note that a point is infinitely small so you will zoom the the maximum view zoom unless you specify `maxZoom` or `minResolution` as a fit option.

Comment: @Mike that's an elegant solution and works nicely. I ended up creating a new Point and then calling fit() with the maxZoom option, like so: olMap.getView().fit(point, { padding: [100, 100, 100, leftPadding], maxZoom:result.zoom, duration:animationSpeed }); and it works perfectly. Feel free to put that as an answer and I'll accept it, otherwise I'll self answer it myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mike](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/102658/mike) in the comments [came up with an elegant solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/396269/openlayers-zoom-to-point-with-padding?noredirect=1#comment648665_396269) that I ended up using. Simply use [`.getView().fit()`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html#fit) with an OpenLayers Point and set a `maxZoom` in the options, like so.

```
let point = new Point(coords);
olMap.getView().fit(point, { 
    padding: [100, 100, 100, leftPadding], 
    maxZoom:result.zoom, 
    duration:animationSpeed 
});
```

Which works perfectly and allows me to continue using the animation speed.